# What does performing regression analysis tell us about our original data?

Tags: regression, linear-model

I am currently trying to find some sort of relationship between two variables. The most obvious way to check for an association between two variables is by examining the correlation coefficient, which I have done. I have also fit a linear model to my data and have come up with a mean squared error value of approximately 0.342. My understanding is that this only tells me about how good the linear model I have fit is to my data is, and does not tell me if there is a relationship between the two variables in question?

Comment: Are you asking us to verify the last claim, or to explain it?

Comment: To me, the most obvious way to find some sort of relationship between two variables is to plot one against the other. Correlation coefficients and (in this case, equivalent) linear models only document _linear_ relations. You can miss a lot by limiting yourself to these linear relations. What do your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

The MSE predicts the parameter value of the mean of the residual values squared. That is, the average distance between a predicted value from your regression best-fit line and the true values in the population you sampled from, then multiplied by itself. Depending on the software/output you could either be reading a biased or unbiased result.

To directly answer your question, the MSE is scale dependent, for very large response variables an MSE of 0.342 would indicate that your regression estimates the sample (and therefore the population, we might infer) very well. For a response variable with smaller values it could be a poorer fit. It does not, on its own, describe the relationship between your response and predictor variables.

Answer (score 0):

As EdM points out, linear models only document linear relationships. Therefore, this answer is making the assumption that you have examined your data graphically and decided that it does follow a linear relationship.

Fitting a linear model of `y~x` is certainly the right place to start, as is examining the MSE, but there is more information that you can extract from the model. First, examine the p-value that should be part of the output. That will tell you if your model is significant or not. Secondly, and more importantly, you should examine the R<sup>2</sup>. You can obtain this simply by squaring your correlation coefficient. Then you can interpret your R<sup>2</sup> as how much variation in `y` is explained by `x`.

So if your R<sup>2</sup> is 0.84 then you can determine that `x` explains 84% of the variation in `y`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data does not follow a linear relationship whatsoever, so I might be wasting my time completely by fitting a linear model.

Comment: Yes, you would be. Can you post an image of a scatterplot? You will likely get much better answers if we can see the relationship